# How do i set an alert for members to prevent them posting in a specific Slack channel?

Tags: slack, slack-commands

I m working in a support role and we used a Slack channel before in which members could report issues. Now, we switched to Jira but members are still reporting in the Slack channel.
Is there possible to create an alert that prevents them to post, like someone is trying to post in the slack channel but after he presses enter, there will show up a pop-up message inviting him to report through Jira or something like this?

Comment: You can limit the posting permissions of the channel. https://slack.com/intl/en-in/help/articles/360004635551-Manage-channel-posting-permissions-

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. Yes, but I would like also people to be informed how's the correct way to report an issue. Like a bot or something like that which sent them a message "Please report it through Jira". Do you have any ideea?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a bot that detects messages on a channel using the event documented [here](https://api.slack.com/events/message.channels)

Upon detecting a message, your bot can send a message on the channel / DM the user / Summon a popup with more information. None of these approaches however would prevent the initial message from being sent.

Overall, I think @SuyashGaur suggestion is the most sound: Make a post with new instructions on the channel, then prevent anyone from further messages. The post should guide them to where they need to go.